# How to make getOne() throw EntityNotFoundError instead of returning a soft-deleted entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, soft-delete

I implemented a *soft-delete* procedure in my database. Here are simplified versions of 2 entities that I am using:

```java
@Entity
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE USER SET DELETED_AT = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE ID = ?")
@Where(clause = "DELETED_AT IS NULL")
public class User {
  
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private Department department;

  private deletedAt = null;

}
```

```java
@Entity
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE DEPARTMENT SET DELETED_AT = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE ID = ?")
@Where(clause = "DELETED_AT IS NULL")
public class Department {
  
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
  private List<User> users;

  private deletedAt = null;

}
```

So every time a delete request is initiated, JPA actually updates the value of the `deletedAt` column with the value of the current timestamp and the `@Where` clause makes sure I only get the records that are not deleted. Everything seems to be working fine. The problem is that in my user service when I want to create a new user object, I need to set the `id` of its department and since **I don't want to make too many requests to the database**, I am using the `getOne` method to create a reference without querying the database.

```java
// Code in my user service.
User newUser = new User();
Department userDepartment = departmentRepository.getOne(departmentId);

newUser.setDepartment(userDepartment);
```

The problem arises when I attempt to assign the `id` of a deleted department to a new user. I want it to throw some exceptions like `EntityNotFount` but since `getOne()` doesn't make any requests to the database, the user understandably gets created. I know there are some alternatives like using `findById()` or `findOne()` but I assume those methods are expensive to use performance-wise. I searched a lot but didn't find any solution to my specific problem. I'm wondering whether there is a workaround that helps me not to directly query the database and yet be able to throw an error when the repository attempts to create a reference of a soft-deleted entity.

Comment: You can't avoid querying the DB and at the same time verify the value of `deletedAt` for a given `Department`. If you want to avoid loading the entire entity, ask for the id only (`SELECT id WHERE id = :id AND deletedAt IS NULL`) before saving a new `User`

Comment: @crizzis thanks. It seems like a better solution if there is no possible way to do it only by creating a reference from the entity. I'm right now sticking to something like that but the problem is that I need to make a dozen of these sorts of queries to the database just to save a single user because my user entity has a lot of relationships around. I just think it's not an efficient way to do this and thought there might be some point that I'm missing.